# Limit: $\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x-2}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone help me understand how the solution for the following limit is $1/4$?

I've been trying to solve it but I always end up in a 'dead end' with an 
indetermination. If someone could help me, that would be awesome.

> $$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x-2}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)$$

Comment: i just edited. sorry

Comment: Hint: Multiply by $(x+2)/(x+2)$ and use $\frac{\sin t}{t} \to 1$ as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Didn't you mean to write $\frac{\sin{(x-2)}}{x+2}$ instead of the entire fraction being an argument? Then it would be simple and you can use the fact that $\sin{x}$ is the same as $x$ around zero.

Comment: no, not really. i meant what i wrote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that for $x\to 2$

$$\frac{1}{x-2}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)}{x-2}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)}{\frac{x-2}{x+2}}\cdot\frac{1}{x+2}\to 1\cdot\frac14=\frac14$$

indeed

$$y=\frac{x-2}{x+2}\to 0 \quad \implies \frac{\sin\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)}{\frac{x-2}{x+2}}=\frac{\sin y}{y}\to1$$

Comment: You divided everything by x+2, is that it?

Comment: @Agapita I've added some detail

Answer (score 2):

You can use $\sin(x)\sim x$ when $x$ tends to $0$. It basically means that you can remove the $\sin$ in your expression. Is it easier then?

Another approach, this limit is by definition the derivative of the function $$g(x)=\sin\left(\dfrac{x-2}{x+2}\right)$$
at $x=2$. If you can compute the derivative of $g$ using the chain rule, all you have to do is replace $x$ with $2$ afterwards.

Comment: and how would you do it exactly? Knowing that this limit tends to 2 and not to 0? Is it possible just to remove it from the limit and let it aside? Thanks

Comment: @Agapita When $x$ tends to $2$, $x-2$ tends to $0$ therefore *what is inside the sin tends to 0*, which is the main point of the first approach.

Comment: @Agapita as $x$ tends to $2$, one has $\frac{x-2}{x+2}$ tends to zero, and $\sin(z)$ as $z$ tends to zero acts like $z$ itself (*where here $z$ can be replaced by $\frac{x-2}{x+2}$*).  Phrased differently, you can remember that $\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+\dots$